# How do I put the contents of the current register into a new buffer in vimscript?

Tags: vim

I am trying to map my F7 key to do the following: take the current register and put it into a new file, which I am opening in a split:

```
 map <F7> :sp clipboard.txt<CR> <bar> :put
```

The first piece works: I get a new buffer in split view called 'clipboard.txt', however, no text gets put.  If I manually type :put in that buffer, the register puts as expected.

How can I script this put?

Comment: Wrong order : `<CR> <bar>` : the command is finished after `<CR>` : you want `map <F7> :sp clipboard.txt <bar> :put <CR>`

Answer (score 3):

Two ways to go about this, you can either use `<cr>` after each command or you can use `<bar>` between multiple commands with a final `<cr>` at the end. Note that you need a `<cr>` at the end, otherwise Vim will just type the command in the command-line and leave it there, waiting for you to press enter.

Also, you should use `nnoremap`, first to make the mapping non-recursive (it would break if you remap the `:` key, for example) and second to make it work in normal mode, which is what's intended, I assume.

Putting it together:

```
nnoremap <F7> :split clipboard.txt<cr>:put<cr>
```

Or:

```
nnoremap <F7> :split clipboard.txt<bar>put<cr>
```

You might want to make that mapping a little more robust and useful, by:

- Deleting the first line, before the pasted contents;
- Making sure that deletion doesn't affect the default register used for pastes (by using the `_` black-hole register)
- Silencing the output of the `:split` and `:put` commands; and
- Silencing the mapping itself.

Resulting in:

```
nnoremap <silent> <F7> :silent split clipboard.txt<bar>silent put<bar>1delete _<cr>
```